# TypeError: multiple values for (named keyword) argument

Tags: python, arguments

I am trying to pass a named keyword argument along with some kwargs and args to a function in Python 3 but am running into a strange problem of the function receiving multiple values for the named argument:

MWE:

```
args = ('arg1_str', 'arg2_str')

def a(positional, named=None, *args, **kwargs):
    print(positional, named, *args, **kwargs)

a("positional_str", named="named_str", *args, kwarg1="kwarg1_str")
```

Expected output:

`positional_str named_str arg1_str arg2_str kwarg1="kwarg1_str"`

Actual output:

`TypeError: a() got multiple values for argument 'named'`

Comment: Keyword-only arguments should be declared after positional. [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `named` is being interpreted as both the `named` keyword argument AND as part of `*args`, hence "multiple values".  It needs to go after `*args` in order to indicate that it can *only* be passed as a keyword argument.

```
args = ('arg1_str', 'arg2_str')

def a(positional, *args, named=None, **kwargs):
    print(positional, named, *args, kwargs)

a("positional_str", named="named_str", *args, kwarg1="kwarg1_str")
```

prints:

```
positional_str named_str arg1_str arg2_str {'kwarg1': 'kwarg1_str'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have all your positional arguments in front of the keyword ones

```
def a(positional, *args, named=None, **kwargs):
    print(positional, named, *args, **kwargs)
```

should get you the desired results